Unreal Engine packaged Project no Response
I had the problem of my game called Rugon not running on win11 anymore. It always shut down after 1 minute.
So after unsuccessfully trying to fix this issue I decided to rebuild the project in UE 5.3 (it was originally built in 4.17).
To make sure there wasn't anything wrong with the engine I first tried to package the project with only the main menu implemented and it worked.
So in the last couple of weeks I completely rebuilt the entire project and debugged it.
It runs smoothly when playing in editor, in standalone, when launching it and also when starting it in shipping mode from VS22.
But when I package the project and run the exe afterwards there is only a black screen and it says "no response" in the taskmanager.
So there is no crash at all and all I can see is a black screen. I can also only shut it down with the task manager.
I uploaded the log to my drive since it was to long to post it here
I really hope someone can help me fixing this issue or give me some hints as where to search.
Cheers,
Marogaz
So far I tried to Fix the redirectors and also to uninstall Quixel Bridge and the WinPix plugin.
Also I have tried packaging this project on 2 different computers. 1 with win11 and 1 with win10. So I think the problem lies within my project but I don't really know where to search anymore. And since there is no crash there is no error that seems to be directly related to the exe not running.
When packaging the project I resolved all errors. But there are still some warnings that I ignored. But those also occur when compiling the project and shouldn't really make any difference.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You say it has errors, but they usually do matter. I never ignore errors when packaging projects.
